# Accessing module's local var

Tags: unit-testing, typescript

For testing reasons, is there a way to access a module's local variable?

```
module m {
   var i = 0;
   export function go() {
       ++i;
   }
}

m.go();
expect(m["i"]).toBe(1); // m["i"] is undefined
```

[That is - is it possible to access a javascript function's local var?]

Ofcourse I can export it, or make it static and wrap it in a class, but I'm looking for something cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

No, looking at the generated JavaScript helps in these situations:

```
var m;
(function (m) {
    var i = 0;
    function go() {
        ++i;
    }
    m.go = go;
})(m || (m = {}));
```

As you can see, `var i` is scoped within the function and therefore inaccessible outside that function.

Just follow your suggestion:

> Of course I can export it, or make it static and wrap it in a class